# Can I flatten a referenced object to XML using attributes?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

If I have the following:

```
public class A
{
   public B b {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Address {get;set;
}
```

what I want is the xml as:

```
<A Name="some data" Address="address..." />
```

So I am trying to flatten my referenced object as attributes.

Is this possible with an XmlSerializer?

Comment: guess this is what you're looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: [Attributes That Control XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e.aspx)

Comment: @Morpheus & M.Babcock: If I have a complex object tree, which part XmlSerializer would I use to flatten objects as xml attributes?

Answer (score 1):

yeah, you can do this by using the IXmlSerializable interface:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass : IXmlSerializable
{
    public MySubClass SubClass { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Name");
        writer.WriteString(SubClass.Name);
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();
        writer.WriteStartAttribute("Phone");
        writer.WriteString(SubClass.Phone);
        writer.WriteEndAttribute();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MySubClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

and then call it like this

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass() {SubClass = new MySubClass() {Name = "Test", Phone = "1234"}};
            serializer.Serialize(writer, myClass);
            string xml = writer.ToString();
        }
```

this is the xml result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyClass Name="Test" Phone="1234" />
```

see msdn too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

or you could just specify the attributes that @Morpheus named ;)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I have a number of complex data structures, so I suppose I would have to create a number of these classes.

Comment: you can just implement the IXmlSerializable interface on your complex classes, but then you have to take care of the complete serialization of this object, including sub-objects. MyClass in my example is your class A. and i forgot to copy the code of MySubClass, that would be your class B, i've updated the code and added MySubClass.